# Laravel redirect in controller from another class

Tags: laravel, redirect

I try co redirect to other route in controller, unfortunately dont work.
My idea is redirect to 'home' when conditions in method canStart from my service class are realize.

**My controller**

```
    public function start($id) {

        $user = auth()->user();

        $this->testService->canStart($id);
        //do something ...
        return view('common/start/',
        [
            'id' => $id,
            'data' => $data,
            'logs' => $logs
        ]);


}
```

**Other Class method**

```
    public function canStart($id) {

    return redirect()->route('home');

    }
```

Comment: if i do everything in my controller it work, but i want separate it

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no errors, view common/start is showed

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You can **start** do something when realize conditions

Comment: It work also when i **return $this->testService->canStart($id);** but it return only sometimes response

Comment: Ok i found answer i should use **redirect()->route('home')->send();**

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function canStart($id) {

            return redirect()->route('home')->send();
}
```

It work now